# C program to merge files not finding EOF, stuck in infinite loop!

Tags: c, algorithm, programming-languages, file-io, loops

I'm having some problems trying to run this program I am working on...The requirements say I was not allowed to use a sort function...I had do something myself....etc.

Pretty much, the program compiles but hangs after executed...I'm guessing it's stuck in an infinite loop...but I can't seem to find it... :(

This program reads to data files that will already be ordered least to greatest and merges them (ordered) into a third .txt file...

The two files are Data1.txt and Data2.txt 
contains:

Data1.txt

```
2
2
2
2
```

Data2.txt

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

combine.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void sortData(FILE *fpData1, FILE *fpData2)
{

 int n, m; 
 FILE *fpMerge;


 fpMerge = fopen("Merge.txt", "w+");


 fscanf(fpData2, "%i", &n);
 fscanf(fpData1, "%i", &m);
 while(n != EOF || m != EOF)
 {

  if(n == EOF)
  {
   fscanf(fpData1, "%i", &m);

   while(m != EOF)
   {

    fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", m);
    fscanf(fpData1, "%i", &m);
   }
  }
  if(m == EOF)
  {
   fscanf(fpData2, "%i", &n);

   while(n != EOF)
   {

    fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", n);
    fscanf(fpData2, "%i", &n);
   }

  }

  if(n < m)
  {
   fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", n);
   fscanf(fpData2, "%i", &n);
  }
  if(n > m)
  {
   fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", m);
   fscanf(fpData1, "%i", &m);
  }
  if(n == m)
  {
   fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", n); 
   fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", m);
   fscanf(fpData2, "%i", &n);
   fscanf(fpData1, "%i", &m);

  }
 }

 fclose(fpMerge);
}

int main (void)
{
 FILE *fpData1;
 FILE *fpData2;


 fpData1 = fopen("Data1.txt", "r");
 if(fpData1 == NULL)
 {
  printf("There was an error opening the file...program terminating..\n");
  exit(1);
 }

 fpData2 = fopen("Data2.txt", "r");
 if(fpData2 == NULL)
 {
  printf("There was an error opening the file...program terminating..\n");
  exit(1);
 }



 sortData(fpData1, fpData2);


 fclose(fpData1);
 fclose(fpData2); 

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"...I'm guessing it's..."_  Have you attached a debugger to see what your program is doing?  Have you tried adding some well-placed debug output statements (using `printf`) to see where it is going wrong?

Comment: I added some printf's and it seems the program is not moving in the file... it stays at the first number and goes forever... is there a better way to move the pointer...cause i'm really not sure...I did it with fscanf earlier i'm not seeing what I did wrong..

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to compare `n != EOF`, but rather the return value of `fscanf`:

```
int count_1;
count_1 = fscanf(fpData1, "%i", &m);
if (count_1 == EOF) // EOF (or error)
{
  // ...
}
```

`fscanf` will also return `EOF` on error. If you need to tell EOF and error conditions apart, use `ferror(fpData1)`, say, and then look up the error code (stored in `errno`).

Comment: could i use (!feof(filename)) then? I was using that to begin with...but I tried changing it to != EOF to see if it made a difference... and it didn't..

Comment: My manual pages say nothing about `fscanf()` setting the stream eof flag (the one `feof()` tests). Why not grab the return value and test if it is `EOF`?

Comment: I figured out my problem.. I hate my loops kind of messed up checking for the wrong EOF. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Your testing of EOF is not quite correct

```
void sortData(FILE *fpData1, FILE *fpData2)
{
    int data1;
    int data2; 
    FILE *fpMerge;

    fpMerge = fopen("Merge.txt", "w+");
    fscanf(fpData1, "%i", &data1);
    fscanf(fpData2, "%i", &data2);

    // While one file still has data        
    while(!feof(fpData1) && !feof(fpData2))
    {
        // Choose 1 file to test
        // Read from that file and put into merge file until either we
        // run out of data or the condition fails.
        if(data1 < data2)
        {
            do {fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", data1);}
            while ((fscanf(fpData1, "%i", &data1) != 0) && (data1 <= data2));
        }
        else
        {
            do {fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", data2);}
            while ((fscanf(fpData2, "%i", &data2) != 0) && (data2 <= data1));
        }
        // NOTE: if fscanf() returns 0 it has failed to read (EOF)
    }
    // One of the files has reached the EOF
    // Dump the other file.
    while(fscanf(fpData1, "%i", &data1) != 0) {fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", data1);}
    while(fscanf(fpData2, "%i", &data2) != 0) {fprintf(fpMerge, "%i\n", data2);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***EOF* is not a character.**
***EOF* is not an integer.**
No files will ever have *EOF* (neither `char` nor `int`) in them.

*EOF* is a condition.
Files will either be on that condition or (usually) not.

You should check the return value of `fscanf()` to detect *EOF* or other problems.

Comment: `EOF` is an integer (or at least convertible to one): it's returned by `int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)`. My copy of `stdio.h` (from eglibc, I think) `#define` s `EOF` as -1. A better statement would be: "If you `fscanf()` into a variable and check that against `EOF`, you're not doing what you think you're doing. You're comparing the value read from the file against whatever your version of `stdio.h` uses to indicate `EOF`, which is almost certainly not what you want."

Comment: Yes, my text was a bit too strong. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yeah... `EOF` is an integer, and `char unsigned` values are a subset of `int` disjoint with the only condition value used in these `f*` stdio functions, `EOF`.